# Lighthouse reduce unused javaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, vite, lighthouse

I run a lighthouse performance test for my website in **build mode**, and one of the suggestions that lighthouse is giving me to improve the performance of my website is:*" Reduce unused JavaScript"*. My project is with **Vite: React + TypeScript**  and the file that lighthouse report flagged as unused javascript is a file with lots of javascript inside it, also inside this file is this comment

```
* @license React
 * react.production.min.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
```

also, this file name starts with index and some random values that I think Vite gives this file on build process: **index-oiHKpnRd.js**

I think that this file is needed but lighthouse flagged this file as unused, but if I remove this file the **website won't work**.

What might this file be? 
Also is there any way to avoid this file affecting my website performance?
[image]

Comment: You're probably pulling in a library that you aren't using. Can you try using react lazy to deal with the issues? Getting rid of that 26k can sometimes cause issues.

Comment: @HSchmale Thanks! The reason was that I was importing a library for later use but I was not using it because the project was not fully completed, after removing the unnecessary imports the warning from lighthouse report was removed also.